kglobalaccel5 registers key pressed events when I don't press anything. What is the event source?
2024 kubuntu is in use. There are two problems on my notebook (it is Honor MagicBook X16 plus, similar to Huawei notebooks):

sometimes brightness is arbitrary self-changing by unknown reason to max or min
sometimes some UI events (generated by unknown source) prevent selecting of text (say in terminal or browser with mouse cursor)

I have tried to find the events source and it seems the first above problem reason is kglobalaccel5 catches events as if brightness changing buttons (Fn + F1 or F2) were pressed. I have got this conclusion on digging in dbus-monitor output.
It is possible to disable brightness-related shortcuts in Settings (then it is possible to set brightness via scrolling on battery tray icon). But the second problem still remains.
In fact arbitrary self-regulated brightness takes place regardless DE (ubuntu-desktop, cinnamon and something else were tried with the same magic). Attempts to find (and disable) something similar to ALS failed.
So the question is: how to determine these events source?

Neither the tile or the question makes any sense. Please change the title to something that is an actual issue and edit the question with details.

@David, I have changed the title the best way I could. As for the question itself, I'm not sure what to change because the question is "who is it?", and the answer is unknown for me. The question is correct, I guess: "how to determine these events source?"

There is no WHO in Ubuntu so no way to help with this. Doubt anyone else here can either.  As long as you keep talking about a ghost no one is going to take this seriously.

@David
Ok, no more ghosts, and the text is absolutely boring and neutral.
